# i have a runtime error in my code that i need to analyse

Tags: c, crash, runtime

i'm learning c and i got a analyse question...
i got this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_ABC_LET 26
void makeABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET]);

int main()
{
   char abcString[NUM_ABC_LET] = "";
   makeABC(abcString);
   puts(abcString);
   return (0);
}

void makeABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET])
{
    char letter;
    for(letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++)
    {
        strcat(abc, letter);
    }
}
```

can any one tell me why will it crash all the time? and what problems it has?

Comment: 1) `strcat` will request the `char*` to the argument. (`strncat(abc, &letter, 1);` instead of. ) 2) `char abcString[NUM_ABC_LET] = "";` --> `char abcString[NUM_ABC_LET+1] = "";` : +1 for null-terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reserve space for 26 alphabets + 1 for the NUL-terminator(`'\0'`).

So change

```
char abcString[NUM_ABC_LET] = "";
```

to

```
char abcString[NUM_ABC_LET + 1] = "";
```

and NUL-terminate it just after the loop in `makeABC` by using

```
abc[NUM_ABC_LET] = '\0';
```

---

Also, as [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) [has mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040206/i-have-a-runtime-error-in-my-code-that-i-need-to-analyse/36040500#comment59730080_36040206), `strcat` requires both its arguments to be strings(`char*`), but you pass a `char*` and a `char` and this causes things to mess up as it invokes Undefined Behavior. So, replace

```
strcat(abc, letter);
```

with something like

```
abc[letter - 'a'] = letter;
```